# Bug in templated conversion operator in GCC: Workaround?

Tags: c++, gcc, implicit-conversion, sfinae

I want to have a class representing a unit with some kind of dimension. This should express something like 1.5m^2. A scalar multiplication with some type shall be allowed and a dimensionless unit should behave exactly like the underlying type. Here is my solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, int Dim>
class Unit {
    public:
    explicit Unit(T t): _value(t) {}

    template<int D = Dim, typename std::enable_if_t<D==0, int> = 0>
    operator T() { static_assert(Dim==0, ""); return _value; } //static_assert not necessary, but gives error if template is removed
    T _value;
};

template<typename S, typename T, int Dim>
auto operator*(S s, Unit<T,Dim> unit)
{
    return Unit<T, Dim>(s * unit._value);
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto i = double{0};

//Scalar test
    auto scalar = int{0};
    auto x = Unit<double,1>(i);
    auto test = scalar * x;

//Conversion test
    auto y = Unit<double,0>(i);
    return y + i;
}
```

This works perfectly fine in clang (https://godbolt.org/z/8Pev7W6Y1). However, due to a GCC bug with templated conversion operators ([Conversion operator: gcc vs clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168022/conversion-operator-gcc-vs-clang)), this does not work in GCC.

It is not possible to remove the SFINAE construction because it (correctly) runs into the `static_assert`.

Do you have an idea for equivalent code that also works in GCC? The code should work in C++17 with both compilers.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you would like to compile, but it fails to compile if the template is removed?  If I remove the template from the godbolt link, both gcc and clang compile the code in the link

Comment: In C++20, `operator T() requires (Dim == 0)` would do the job [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K6rzd8Md9).

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think it is the opposite `static_cast<double>(Unit<double,2>(0))` would incorrectly compile without the SFINAE (and the `static_assert`)

Comment: @Jarod42 I get that, but if they leave the static assert in, it will still fail to compile.  I'm trying to understand *It is not possible to remove the SFINAE construction because it (correctly) runs into the static_assert*.  I'm not sure what that means

Comment: You're right, I have messed up the minimal example (and failed and checking). The problem in my real example is that the conversion operator is tried before the given `operator*` and then runs into the `static_assert`. I am trying to fix the example.

Comment: Not sure if it is applicable to the use-case, but the [Boost Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) could be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use specialization instead of SFINAE. To avoid too much duplication you can move the common parts (anything that does not depend on `Dim`) to a base class:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class base_unit {
    public:
    explicit base_unit(T t): _value(t) {}
    T _value;
};


template<typename T, int Dim>
class Unit : public base_unit<T> {
public:
    explicit Unit(T t): base_unit<T>(t) {}
};

template <typename T>
class Unit<T,0> : public base_unit<T> {
public:
    explicit Unit(T t) : base_unit<T>(t) {}
    operator T() { return base_unit<T>::_value; }
};

template<typename S, typename T, int Dim>
auto operator*(S s, Unit<T,Dim> unit)
{
    return Unit<T, Dim>(s * unit._value);
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto i = double{0};

//Scalar test
    auto scalar = int{0};
    auto x = Unit<double,1>(i);
    auto test = scalar * x;

//Conversion test
    auto y = Unit<double,0>(i);
    return y + i;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nqEaxWYv9)

Note that this is a little old-fashioned and does not consider more modern C++20 approaches (for example the `operator T() requires (Dim == 0)` mentioned in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have an idea for equivalent code that also works in GCC? The code should work in C++17 with both compilers.

Since you don't want the code on the call side to be changed and the problem is with `y+i`, you could overload `operator+` as shown below:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T, int Dim>
class Unit {
    public:
    explicit Unit(T t): _value(t) {}

    template<int D = Dim, typename std::enable_if_t<D==0, int> = 0>
    operator T() { static_assert(Dim==0, ""); return _value; } //static_assert not necessary, but gives error if template is removed
    T _value;
    //overload operator+
    template<typename U,int D, typename V>  friend U operator+( Unit<U,D>& u,  V& v);  
};
//define overloaded operator+
template<typename U, int D, typename V> U operator+( Unit<U,D>& u,  V&v)
{
    std::cout<<u.operator U() + v;//just for checking the value
    return u.operator U() + v;
}
template<typename S, typename T, int Dim>
auto operator*(S s, Unit<T,Dim> unit)
{
    return Unit<T, Dim>(s * unit._value);
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto i = double{0};

//Scalar test
    auto scalar = int{0};
    auto x = Unit<double,1>(i);
    auto test = scalar * x;

//Conversion test
    auto y = Unit<double,0>(i);
    
    return y + i;
}
```

The output the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vdr4SRtGrOnEDgIe).

Comment: I think OP wants implicit conversions to `T` (where explicitly calling the converision operator doesn't help). I mean "stating the obvious" is good, but I am not sure if this is what OP calls "equivalent code"

Comment: Yes, the code should not be changed on the calling side.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But OP didn't mention this important thing in his/her question.

Comment: not sure if you got my point. OPs conversion operator is implicit. While your answer is a workaround it isnt one for implicit conversions.

Comment: @AnoopRana Actually the OP did.  They said *Do you have an idea for equivalent code that also works in GCC* which to me reads I don't want to change the driver code, only the code it calls

Comment: @NathanOliver That is your interpretation of the quoted statement.

Comment: @Henk I have edited my answer to use overloaded `operator+` which needs no change on the caller side. Check it out.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have edited my answer to use overloaded `operator+` which needs no change on the caller side. Check it out.

Comment: You would need this overloading for every possible situation to get implicit conversion with this approach in gcc.

Comment: @Henk yes that is the downside. For example, for `y * i` or `y - i`  to work you/we would have to overloaded the respective operators as well. But still it solves(or is one possible way of solving) the current problem.